# Dialog and SQL output on Linux Shell Scripting

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, shell, dialog

I have the following script:

```
VAR=$(mysql -u root -e " use <database_name>; select column1,column2,column3 from <table_name>;")

dialog --title "something" --msgbox "$VAR" 50 50
```

and the output that I got is like this.
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAYrb.png)
but i'm expecting the output to be like this instead inside the dialog command
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiQeJ.png)

I can get this output by not storing the sql commands in a variable.

where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

On your `VAR=$(mysql ...)`, you can add `--table` to get the disired effect.

```
VAR=$(mysql -u root -t -e ...)
```

Comment: well It did work but the columns are not equal even if the width and hieght pixel of my dialog box is dyanmic.

Comment: Can you share output with a picture ?

Comment: posted, I'm new to this hehe